SWIG: %pythonappend on every method of a class
I am looking for a way to apply %pythonappend to all methods of a class. Not sure if an example is required here but lets say I have this
myheader.hpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


class SampleClass
{
public:
    std::vector<double>* m_v;
    SampleClass(std::vector<double>* v) : m_v {v} {
     std::cout << "\nnon default constructor!\n";}

    SampleClass() {std::cout << "default constructor!\n";}
    double SampleMethod(std::vector<double>* arg);
    int SampleMethod2(std::vector<double>* arg);
    ...
};

And a trivial .i file to cover that.
What I am looking for is something like %pythonappend SampleClass::*  %{ # Do python stuff %}
I've also tried %feature("pythonappend", %$isfunction) SampleClass which doesn't work either.
At this point I am not sure if that is even possible through SWIG or if I should go a different route, possibly dynamically using setattr on the class itself when it's called (I'd really rather not do that).

Do not tag C for C++ questions.

I am the author of SWIG JSE (JavaScript Evolution) and %feature for all members of class is available in SWIG JSE and it is in a PR for the main trunk - which means that I can guarantee you that this feature is not in SWIG master
